# how to show the div when clicked on the link and how to get value from input?

Tags: html, django, templates

i have a django template that uses for loop to print comments i want to show the input field and a button when the edit link is clicked how do i do that.
and also when the edit button is pressed i wanna get the value from that specific input field. how do i do that?

```
{% for comment in comments %}
<div class="comment mdl-color-text--grey-700">
   <header class="comment__header">
      <img src="images/co1.jpg" class="comment__avatar">
      <div class="comment__author">
         <strong>{{comment.User_name}}</strong>
         <span>{{comment.date}}</span>
      </div>
   </header>
   <div class="comment__text">
      {{comment.text}}
   </div>
   <!-- FAB button , class  "mdl-button--fab"-->
   <a href="javascript:delete_comment('{{comment.text}}','{{comment.blogslug}}')">
   <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab">
   <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
   </button>
   </a>
    <!--when this link is clicked bellow edit_comment div should appear -->
   <a href="">
   <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab">
   <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
   </button>
   </a>
    <!-- and also when i click the edit button how can i get value from the input -->
    <div id="edit_comment" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <input type="text" name="edit_comment">
        <button>edit</button>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

so the problem is there are going to many other comments of this type because they are printed using a loop.

Comment: Get a counter in your for loop using `{{ forloop.counter }}` and add that to the `id` attribute of your `div`s. Pass that as an argument into your JavaScript function when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why are you wrapping your button in an `<a>` tag? Unnecessary.

Get rid of `visibility: hidden`. Use `display: none` or a class like Bootstrap's `d-none`.

I suggest `d-none` because it allows you to add the class and remove it without worrying about the inherited display property, i.e. `display: flex` or `display: block`.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Write a custom function with an event listener.

Inside your template loop:

```html
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab" onclick="handleClick(this)">
   <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
</button>
```

*ASSUMING YOU HAVE REMOVED THE `<a>` TAG*

JavaScript:

```js
let handleClick = function(param) {
    let editCommentDiv = param.parentNode.lastChild;
    editCommentDiv.style.display = "none"
};
```

This is by no means the best way to do it. I highly suggest you use BootStrap's `d-none` class. Also, what you should actually do is assign an ID based on the for loop to both the button and to the div, i.e. `id=editcommentdiv_{{ forloop.counter }}` this way you won't need to use DOM to navigate to the last element to get the edit div, and can just target the div directly via ID.

Comment: In the same JavaScript function after editCommentDiv, editCommentDiv.firstChild.value

Comment: Again, you should be using IDs though